# Assigning damage to multiple blockers

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Okay so when I was looking up the answer to a different question I had I found this

> You assign 2 damage on the first target, but he's not dead yet until you assign all 5 damage that you have. So all the remaining creature are still 2/2 so you are forces to a assign at least 2 damages on each so assign 2 damage on the second in the row, and 1 damage to the 3rd creature for a grand total of 5 damages. The forth creature receive no damage.

So if this is correct, this is something I didn't know about blocking multiple creatures (I'm fairly new to the game and have never actually had it happen, only been reading about the fact that you can double block)

So if I attack with 6/6, and am blocked with 4/4 and 2/3

This is how I thought it worked

- I choose order of 4/4 then 2/3
- So 4/4 dies because I did 6 damage, 6/6 took 4
- 2/3 dies because I did 6 damage, 6/6 took 2
- My 6/6 died because it took a total of 6 damage

So is that correct? Or is it like this

- Attack with 6/6
- Blocked by 4/4 and 2/3
- Order of 4/4 then 2/3, 4 damage and 2 damage (Total of 6, my creatures attack number)
- 4/4 dies because it took 4 damage, 6/6 takes 4 damage
- 2/3 lives because it took 2 damage, 6/6 take 2 damage
- My 6/6 dies because it took a total of 6 damage

[Source](http://community.wizards.com/content/forum-topic/2363271)

Comment: Note that the formatting is not coming out the way you are intending here. On this site, when you place just a single new line in your text, it treats it just like a space. This is causing your questions to look like they are missing punctuation and making them hard to read correctly. You can check the question preview as you are typing to see how it will look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the second one. Because your creature has a power of 6, you can deal a total of 6 damage during combat. If you are blocked by 2 creatures, you can choose how to divide that 6 damage between the 2 blocking creatures (though you you have assign lethal damage to one of them in order to also deal damage to the other). You don't get to deal 6 damage to each creature.

Answer (score 6):

The latter. Each creature deals damage equal to its power to all blockers, attackers and defending players or planeswalkers, not to each of them.

Simultaneously,

- The 6/6 deals 4 damage to the 4/4<sup>[1]</sup>.
- The 6/6 deals 2 damage to the 2/3.
- The 4/4 deals 4 damage to the 6/6.
- The 2/3 deals 2 damage to the 6/6.

Shortly after, when State-Based Actions are performed, the following happens simultaneously:

- The 6/6 is destroyed for having damage equal to or exceeding its toughness.
- The 4/4 is destroyed for having damage equal to or exceeding its toughness.

---

1. That's assuming the minimum damage is dealt to each creature. You can choose to "overkill" if you so desire, but it's rarely helpful.

Comment: His first scenario, what he thought was true, is that his creature deals 6 damage to EACH of the blocking creatures.

Comment: They are different because in one, the 2/3 survives because I was only allowed to deal 2 damage to it because I already used 4 damage on the 4/4 to kill it

Comment: Regarding "overkill is rarely helpful", it's quite common to have combat tricks that will allow a creature to survive the initially allocated amount of damage so if you are more interested in killing one over the other you may want to factor in whatever combat tricks the opponent might have available and then assign your damage whilst taking that into account.

Comment: @Cronax, That makes no sense. There's no chance to do any "combat tricks" after damage is assigned. (510.1. First, the active player announces how each attacking creature assigns its combat damage, then the defending player announces how each blocking creature assigns its combat damage. [...] 510.2. Second, all combat damage that’s been assigned is dealt simultaneously. [...]) The only time it makes sense to overkill is when abilities (such as Lifelink) there are abilities that check how much damage was done, or when shields *that are already in place* would reduce the damage.

Comment: @ikegami as far as I am aware, as seen in http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Declare_Blockers_Step part 509.5 is the moment where you could play combat tricks but where damage assignment order has already been declared

Comment: @Cronax, Damage assignment order, yes, but not damage assignment. The "common combat tricks" you mentioned earlier are illegal. You can't use any abilities or cast any spells after damage has been assigned (or "allocated", as you called it). As such, there's very rarely any reason to overkill.

Comment: @ikegami I interpret the rules to mean that the player never actually decides how much damage to assign to each blocker but only the order in which damage will be assigned until you reach the maximum amount of damage for that attacker. When the blockers are 4/4 and 2/2 and you have a 6/6 this means the blocking player can make the 4/4 into a 5/5 to save the 2/2. This matters more when you are giving both blockers +1/+1, since if only the order is decided, the 4/4 will never live, whereas if the actual amount of damage is also decided, both 4/4 and 2/2 can live.

Comment: @Cronax, "both 4/4 and 2/2 can live", No, the 4/4 can't live if the damage assignment order is 4/4 then 2/2, and if the 4/4 becomes a 5/5.

Comment: @ikegami doesn't that mean that you never have a chance to overkill?

Comment: @Cronax, huh? In step 1 of my answer, the 6/6 could have done 5 or 6 damage to the 4/4, overkilling it. The 2/2 would have survived, though. Like I said, rarely any reason to do that.